# Unable to select custom jquery autocomplete item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Can anyone please help me figure out why am I not able to select any of the autocomplete items? I am trying to customize the value the items are displayed. Also, why is jquery matching only on the country name and not the id i.e. if i enter 17 i should expect to see Albania come up in the selction but it doesnt?

http://jsfiddle.net/RTn4c/1/

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
    source: countries_starting_with_A,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // feed hidden id field
        $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
        // update number of returned rows
        $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // update number of returned rows
        var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
        $('#results_count').html('(#' + len + ')');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // update number of returned rows
        $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    // mustMatch implementation
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item === null) {
            $(this).val('');
            $('#field_id').val('');
        }
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                return $("<li></li>")
                .append("<span>" + item.value + ' ' + item.id + " </span> ")
                .appendTo(ul);
            };

// mustMatch (no value) implementation
$("#field").focusout(function() {
    if ($("#field").val() === '') {
        $('#field_id').val('');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Have you checked your console for error?

Comment: I did, but no errors at all. I also added some logging code on the select handler but that wasnt triggered too